# Minimal polynomial of polynomial quotient field linear transfomation over finite field

Tags: linear-algebra, finite-fields, irreducible-polynomials, minimal-polynomials

$
\DeclareMathOperator{\sgn}{sgn}
\DeclareMathOperator{\Res}{Res}
\DeclareMathOperator{\VP}{V.P.}
%\DeclareMathOperator{\CCC}{C^1}
\DeclareMathOperator{\contt}{C}
\DeclareMathOperator{\PCC}{PC}
\DeclareMathOperator{\re}{Re}
\DeclareMathOperator{\im}{Im}
%\DeclareMathOperator{\dd}{d}
\newcommand{\ph}{\varphi}
\newcommand{\inth}{\int_{-h}^0}
\newcommand{\teta}{\theta}
\newcommand{\R}{\mathbb{R}}
\renewcommand{\C}{\mathbb{C}}
\newcommand{\N}{\mathbb{N}}
\newcommand{\<}{\leq}
\renewcommand{\>}{\geq}
\renewcommand{\d}{\mathrm{d}}
\newcommand{\Int}{\int\limits}
\newcommand{\Sum}{\sum\limits}
\newcommand{\Max}{\max\limits}
\newcommand{\Sup}{\sup\limits}
\newcommand{\Lim}{\lim\limits}
\newcommand{\lmin}{\lambda_{\min}}
\newcommand{\eqdef}{\stackrel{\mathrm{def}}{=}}
\newcommand{\pc}[4]{\PCC_{#1}^{#2}\br{#3,#4}}
\newcommand{\mh}{\mathfrak{h}}
\newcommand{\bh}{\mathbf h}
\newcommand{\bN}{\mathbf N}
\newcommand{\eps}{\varepsilon}
\newcommand{\dt}{\mathrm{d}t}
\newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
\newcommand{\x}{\textup{x}}
\newcommand{\y}{\textup{y}}
\newcommand{\w}{\textup{w}}
\newcommand{\al}{\alpha}
\newcommand{\ti}{\times}
\newcommand{\D}{\Delta}
\newcommand{\del}{\delta}
\newcommand{\til}[1]{\widetilde{#1}}
%\newcommand{\CC}[2]{\CCC\br{#1,#2}}
%\newcommand{\cc}[3]{\CCC_#1\br{#2,#3}}
\renewcommand{\c}[4]{\contt_{#1}^{#2}\br{#3,#4}}
\newcommand{\F}[1]{\mathbb{F}_{#1}}$
Consider finite field $\F{p},$ irreducible $q(x)\in\F{p}[x]$ with $\deg q=n\>1$, and mapping
$$
\ph:~\F{p}[x]/(q(x))\to\F{p}[x]/(q(x)),~[f(x)]\mapsto [f(x^p)]\quad\forall f(x)\in\F{p}[x].
$$
I know that $\ph$ is well-defined mapping and is linear transformation between vector spaces over $\F{p}$. I'd like to find the minimal polynomial of $\ph.$

The solution to this problem claims that $g(x)=x^n-1\in\F{p}[x]$ is the answer. I have that:

1. $\F{p}[x]/(q(x))\simeq\F{p^n}$;
2. $y^{p^n}=y\quad\forall y\in\F{p^n}$;
3. Degree of a polynomial over field is not less than number of its roots. Therefore $\deg f\> p^n$ if all elements of $\F{p^n}$ are roots of $f(x)\in\F{p}[x]$ with $\deg f\> 1.$
4. $\Sum_{j=1}^m f_j(x)^{p}=\left(\Sum_{j=1}^m f_j(x)\right)^{p}\quad\forall \{f_j(x)\}_{j=1}^m\subset\F{p}[x],~\forall m\in\N\setminus\{0\}$;
5. $f(x^{p})=f(x)^{p}\quad\forall f(x)\in\F{p}[x]$;
6. $\ph([f(x)])=[f(x)]^p\quad\forall f(x)\in\F{p}[x]$;
7. $\ph^n:~[f(x)]\mapsto [f(x)]\quad\forall f(x)\in\F{p}[x]$;
8. Minimal polynomial divides characteristic one and any annihilating polynomial.
9. Irreducible polynomial has a root iff it is linear. Therefore $g(x)$ is reducible (since it has root $1$). But why factors of $g(x)$ are not annihilating at $\ph$?

Seventh point implies that $g(x)=x^n-1$ is annihilating polynomial of $\ph.$ Why the third one gives here that $g(x)$ is minimal?

Comment: You need the polynomial $q(x)$ to be *irreducible* for otherwise the quotient ring will not be a field.

Comment: If $g(x)$ were not the minimal polynomial, then the minimal polynomial $m(x)$ would have degree $<n$. But in that case $m(\phi)$ would be a polynomial of degree $<p^n$. Yet, it will have $p^n$ zeros in the field $\Bbb{F}_{p^n}$. This is a contradiction and also explains why we needed $q(x)$ to be irreducible.

Comment: I explained this as a key component [of this old answer of mine](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/53316/11619), so perhaps I should just comment this time.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen My bad, forgot to mention that $q$ is irreducible. Thank you for your comments! Now it is evident that I should have considered $m(\phi(\cdot))$ as polynomial over $\mathbb{F}_{p^n}.$