# Determine a basis for $\Bbb F_p[\omega]/\Bbb F_p$.

Tags: galois-theory, finite-fields, cyclotomic-fields

Fix a prime $p$. Let $\Bbb F_p$ be the finite field with $p$ elements with $\omega$ a primitive $n^{th}$ root of unity. From Galois theory of finite fields, the extension $\Bbb F_p[\omega]/\Bbb F_p$ is Galois with degree $$\left[\Bbb F_p[\omega]:\Bbb F_p\right]=\left|\operatorname{Gal}(\Bbb F_p[\omega]/\Bbb F_p)\right|=\left|\left<\sigma_p\right>\right|,$$ where $\sigma_p(\omega) = \omega^p$.

So that the degree of the extension $\Bbb F_p[\omega]/\Bbb F_p$ is exactly the order of $p$ in $(\Bbb Z/n\Bbb Z)^{\times}$. I am guessing that $$\omega,\omega^p,\omega^{p^2},...$$ is a set of basis. This has the right length as a basis, but I struggled to prove this spans $\Bbb F_p[\omega]$ over $\Bbb F_p$. How can one show it spans?

Comment: Isn't this a simple extension? If degree of the extension is $k$, then $1, \omega, \omega^2,\dots, \omega^{k-1}$ forms a basis.

Comment: The conjugates of $\omega$ need not form a basis. Possibly the simplest to describe case when this fails is $p=3$, $n=4$. Customarily the symbols $i$ is often used for a fourth root of unity, so I use it instead of $\omega$. It is in the quadratic extension of $\Bbb{F}_p$ as a root of $x^2+1$. However, its conjugate is $i^3=-i$, and surely $\{i,-i\}$ is linearly dependent :-)

Comment: (cont'd) A slightly more complicated example occurs when $p=2$, $n=7$.  We have the modulo two factorization
$$x^7-1=(x-1)(x^3+x+1)(x^3+x^2+1),$$ so the roots of $x^3+x+1$ are seventh roots of unity. If $\omega$ is one of them, by Galois theory, the other two are $\omega^2$ and $\omega^4$. So in the splitting field
$$x^3+x+1=(x-\omega)(x-\omega^2)(x-\omega^4).$$
Expanding the right hand side and comparing the coefficients of the quadratic terms gives the linear dependency relation
$$0=\omega+\omega^2+\omega^4.$$

Comment: (cont'd) However, the roots of the other cubic factor do form a basis. To close I give you the buzzword *normal basis*. Feed that into a search engine (of the on-site search), and you will find a lot of hits such as [this old answer of mine](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/53316/11619). So every extension of finite fields has a normal basis, but it's not immediately clear to me for which choices of $n$ such a basis exists.

Comment: A point worth bearing in mind is that every non-zero element of every finite field is **a primitive root of unity of some order**. In this sense roots of unity abound in the realm of finite fields :-)